# leaflet: Zooming a tile cache

Tags: leaflet

I have a NASA BlueMarble tile layer that goes from zoom factors 0-8. I when I go to zoom level 9, I do see a momentary scaling to 9 (stretching pixels). But  then, as expected, I get the errorTileUrl.  Nothing wrong here.
But rather than have to created the tile cache (and massive data store) for zoom factors 9-14 or so, how would one go about having those zoom factors be pixel scaling and stretching?

This would be very useful for my offline maps.

Ideas?

(BTW, any suggestions for how to store offline tile caches? Say 2K to 4K of tiles in PNG format? Would I use an app manifest? (web application)?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [ZoomTMSLayer](https://github.com/tilemapjp/ZoomTMSLayer) library, this will stretch the tiles at the client end when zooming beyond the tiles available on the server.

Comment: I looked at it, but it seems to only work for TMS Tile Layers, and the ones I want to use are using the inverted Y axis (CloudMade, OSM, etc.). In addition, I need to use a functional Tile Layer. See my issue post at: https://github.com/tilemapjp/ZoomTMSLayer/issues/4